# Android: Paint.measureText() unexpectedly rounds in 4.4?

Tags: android

I make heavy use of the `Paint.measureText()` method and was surprised to find that in 4.4 the `float` this method returns is always rounded up.  In previous versions, no rounding occurred.  I ran the below code on a 4.0.4 device and a 4.4 device.   The results for the 4.0.4 device are first, the results for the 4.4 device are second.

Any suggestions of how I can get unrounded values in 4.4, possibly there is a new attribute for `Paint` that I missed?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL));
    p.setTextSize(1);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setSubpixelText(true);

    Log.e("T", p.measureText("T")+"");
    Log.e("h", p.measureText("h")+"");
    Log.e("e", p.measureText("e")+"");
    Log.e("L", p.measureText("L")+"");
    Log.e("a", p.measureText("a")+"");
    Log.e("z", p.measureText("z")+"");
    Log.e("y", p.measureText("y")+"");
    Log.e("w", p.measureText("w")+"");
}
```

4.0.4:

0.59375
0.5625
0.515625
0.546875
0.546875
0.5
0.5
0.75

4.4:

1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0

Comment: Sad to hear that, but it seems that it happens way before KitKat. Have you tried other measures like getTextBounds or getTextWidths?

Comment: Have you got it fixed ?